# How to update webpage based on selection from dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, redux, updates

I have a webpage that is displaying a list of movies from an API. As you can see in my code, right under the render method I have three commented out sort methods that works fine, when I uncomment one of the methods it does the sort as intended.

What I want to happen is that when the user clicks on one of the options from the select dropdown list, it updates the webpage accordingly.

I thought an onClick on one of the options would do it, but it does not work. My guess right now is it has something to do with the mapped content that I have showing up on the page when it loads, but I am not completely sure.

Here's my code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {crimeGenre} from "./redux";

class CrimeGenre extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.crimeGenre();
    }

    sortAlpha = () => {
        return this.props.select && this.props.select.sort((a, b) => {
            a.title < b.title ? -1 : 1;
        });
    }

    render(){
        // this.props.select && this.props.select.sort((a, b) => {
        //     return a.title < b.title ? -1 : 1;
        // });

        // this.props.select && this.props.select.sort((a, b) => {
        //     return a.vote_average > b.vote_average ? -1 : 1;
        // });

        // this.props.select && this.props.select.sort((a, b) => {
        //     return a.popularity > b.popularity ? -1 : 1;
        // });
        const mappedSelected = this.props.select && this.props.select.map((film, i) => { 
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>{film.title}</h1>
                    <img src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185${film.poster_path}`}/>
                    <p>Avg. User Score: {film.vote_average}</p>
                </div>
            )
        })

        return(
            <div>
            <select>
                <option onClick={this.sortAlpha}>Alphabetically</option>
                <option>User Score</option>
                <option>Popularity</option>
            </select>
                {mappedSelected}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(state=> state, {crimeGenre})(CrimeGenre);
```

**UPDATE: HERE'S MY CURRENT CODE**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {crimeGenre} from "./redux";

class CrimeGenre extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            value: "alphabetically"
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.crimeGenre();
    }

    sortFilms = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        })
        if(this.state.value === "alphabetically"){
            return this.props.select && this.props.select.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.title < b.title ? -1 : 1;
            });
        }else if(this.state.value === "score"){
            return this.props.select && this.props.select.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.vote_average > b.vote_average ? -1 : 1;
            });
        }else if(this.state.value === "popularity"){
            return this.props.select && this.props.select.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.popularity > b.popularity? -1 : 1;
            });
        }
    }

    render(){
        const mappedSelected = this.props.select && this.props.select.map((film, i) => { 
            return (
                <div key={i}>
                    <h1>{film.title}</h1>
                    <img src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185${film.poster_path}`}/>
                    <p>Avg. User Score: {film.vote_average}</p>
                    <p>Popularity Index: {film.popularity.toFixed(0)}</p>
                </div>
            )
        })

            return(
                <div>
                <form>
                    <label>
                        Sort By:
                        <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.sortFilms}>
                            <option id="alphabetically" value="alphabetically">Alphabetically</option>
                            <option id="score" value="score">User Score</option>
                            <option id="popularity" value="popularity">Popularity</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </form>
                    {mappedSelected}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

export default connect(state=> state, {crimeGenre})(CrimeGenre);
```

Comment: Your answer in [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag)

Comment: Hey @RaphaMex the info in the documentation made it sort of work. It updates the page, but it doesn't sort by the right one. It sorts by the option before the one I selected.

For example, if I choose to sort by User Score, it sorts alphabetically which is the option before it in the dropdown.

Comment: OK, post your new code so I can have a look at it :-)

Comment: I updated the post with my new code. Also I figured out that it's not necessarily sorting by the one before in the dropdown, but by the option that the user specifically chose beforehand. 

For example, when the user first selects User Score and then chooses another option it sorts by what the user chose before which was User Score. i hope that made sense haha.

Comment: You use index `i` as key instead of a real key. That's typically why React cannot update the new order. Choose `film.poster_path` instead, so react will detect elements changed place.

Comment: That didn't work either. When you say to choose `film.poster_path` you meant to just replace the `i` in the key with that right? Man, what could be the issue?

Comment: Yes. You are almost there. `this.setState` is asynchronous. Record `event.target.value` in a const variable first before calling setState. Also, do the sorting in the render function just before mapping to jsx.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are now close to a working solution. I can recommend this code that fixes some small remaining issues:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {crimeGenre} from "./redux";

class CrimeGenre extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        // Do not use component's STATE if you are using REDUX, use redux state container
        this.state = {
            value: "alphabetically"
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.crimeGenre();
    }

    setOrder = (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value; // Save static value here, event may change
        this.setState({value}); // Asynchronous, `this.state.value` is not updated yet
    }

    render(){
        let mappedSelected = [];

        if (this.props.select) {
            // `this.state.value` is now updated, sort `props` accordingly
            switch (this.state.value) {
            case "alphabetically":
                this.props.select.sort((a, b) => (a.title < b.title ? -1 : 1));
                break;
            case "score":
                this.props.select.sort((a, b) => (a.vote_average > b.vote_average ? -1 : 1));
                break;
            case "popularity":
                this.props.select.sort((a, b) => (a.popularity > b.popularity? -1 : 1));
                break;
            }

            mappedSelected = this.props.select.map((film) => { 
                return (
                    // Never use index as key
                    <div key={film.poster_path}>
                      <h1>{film.title}</h1>
                      <img src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185${film.poster_path}`}/>
                      <p>Avg. User Score: {film.vote_average}</p>
                      <p>Popularity Index: {film.popularity.toFixed(0)}</p>
                    </div>
                );
            });
        }

        return(
            <div>
              <form>
                <label>
                  Sort By:
                  <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.setOrder}>
                    <option id="alphabetically" value="alphabetically">Alphabetically</option>
                    <option id="score" value="score">User Score</option>
                    <option id="popularity" value="popularity">Popularity</option>
                  </select>
                </label>
              </form>
              {mappedSelected}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(state=> state, {crimeGenre})(CrimeGenre);
```

Last point to address would be that you use Redux. Here is a pure React solution. If still possible, I recommend you give yourself some time to understand React before you start integrating Redux.